# How to open a game from python

Tags: python

I want to open a file and then run a game from in it. I tried:

```
import os

os.startfile(r'C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/Jnes')    
os.startfile("Jnes.exe")
```

But that only brought up the first file and didn't run the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is superfluous. The parent Python process still has it's default working directory. That line will not change it, so the second line will fail as it will not find the file named `Jnes.exe`.

So either use:

```
os.startfile(r'C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/Jnes/Jnes.exe')
```

This will keep the working directory (for the Python process) unchanged, or, if you want it changed, use:

```
os.chdir(r'C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/Jnes')    
os.startfile("Jnes.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

import random

class Player:
def **init**(self, name, health):
self.name = name
self.health = health

```
def attack(self):
    return random.randint(1, 10)
```

def battle(player1, player2):
print(f"{player1.name} vs {player2.name}")

```
while player1.health > 0 and player2.health > 0:
    player1_damage = player1.attack()
    player2_damage = player2.attack()

    print(f"{player1.name} deals {player1_damage} damage to {player2.name}")
    player2.health -= player1_damage

    print(f"{player2.name} deals {player2_damage} damage to {player1.name}")
    player1.health -= player2_damage

    print(f"{player1.name} health: {player1.health}")
    print(f"{player2.name} health: {player2.health}")
    print("")

if player1.health > player2.health:
    print(f"{player1.name} wins!")
elif player2.health > player1.health:
    print(f"{player2.name} wins!")
else:
    print("It's a draw!")
```

player1 = Player("Player 1", 100)
player2 = Player("Player 2", 100)

battle(player1, player2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).